# Missing viewport meta tag

Tags: html, viewport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>B&B Acqua e Fuoco</title>
        <link href="navbarst.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style>
           body { 
               background:url("back.jpg"); 
               background-repeat: no-repeat;
               background-size: cover;
           }
           div {
               border: 4px solid black;
               margin-top: 140px;
               margin-bottom: 100px;
               margin-right: 450px;
               margin-left: 450px;
               padding-top: 40px;
               padding-right: 40px;
               padding-bottom: 40px;
               padding-left: 40px;
               background: rgba(56, 59, 63, 0.6); 
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img alt="Contenuto non mostrabile" src="star.png"> <img alt=
            "Contenuto non mostrabile" src="star.png"> <img alt=
            "Contenuto non mostrabile" src="star.png"> <b><font color="black" face=
            "Arial" size="6">B&B Acqua e Fuoco<br>
            <br></font></b> <b><font color="black" face="Arial" size="4"></font></b>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="Home.html" title="Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="prezzi/Prezzi.html" title="Prezzi">Prezzi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="prezzi/Prezzi.html" title="Servizi">Servizi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="gallery/gallery.html" title="Gallery">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="flat/flat.html" title="Etna mini flat">Etna mini flat</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Links/links.html" title="Links">Links</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contatti/contatti.html" title="Contatti">Contatti</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" target="_blank" title=
                "Guarda la nostra posizione su Google Maps!">Mappa</a>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right">
                <a href="Home.html" title="Italiano"><img src="it.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right">
                <a href="en/Home.html" title="English"><img src="en.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right">
                <a href="en/Home.html" title="English"><img src="de.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right">
                <a href="en/Home.html" title="English"><img src="fr.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="float:right">
                <a href="en/Home.html" title="English"><img src="es.png"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't insert the viewport command, i tried everything but my code doesn't see it...there is something wrong? Except my question, there is anything else wrong/miss? i'm a beginner and i followed some guides to arrive at this point of the site

Comment: Your html code is not 100% valid, you are missing different meta tags and `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top. See [HTML5 Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp)

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width> i mean this

Comment: @xenus97it Where is that meta tag being inserted? Is the code you've shared above being generated by some framework/templating library?